# Raycaster sometimes renders walls in the wrong order

Tags: rust, rendering, raycasting

I made a very basic raycasting engine from the formula laid out in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYRrGTC7GtA) video in Rust. this works fine and is very flexible, however when it renders two connecting blocks, it sometimes renders the wrong wall.
I am fairly certain that this is a rounding error, as I had trouble with that in the past, but I cannot find where it is.

The code, in full, is:

```
const SCREEN_WIDTH: f32 = 750f32;
const SCREEN_HEIGHT: f32 = 500f32;
const SCREEN_OFFSET: f32 = SCREEN_WIDTH / 100f32;

const SHOW_2D_RAYS: bool = false;
const SHOW_2D_LEVEL: bool = false;

const CELL_SIZE: f32 = SCREEN_HEIGHT / MAP_SIZE;

const level: [[f32; MAP_SIZE as usize]; MAP_SIZE as usize] = [
    [ 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, ],
    [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, ],
    [ 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, ],
    [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, ],
    [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, ],
    [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, ],
    [ 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, ],
    [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, ],
    [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, ],
    [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, ],
    [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, ],
    [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, ],
    [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, ],
    [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, ],
    [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, ],
    [ 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, ],
    [ 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, ],
    [ 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, ],
    [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, ],
    [ 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, ],
];

fn draw_level() {
    for i in 0..MAP_SIZE as usize {
        for j in 0..MAP_SIZE as usize {
            if level[i][j] > 0f32 {
                draw_rectangle(
                    (j as f32 * CELL_SIZE) + 1f32,
                    (i as f32 * (SCREEN_HEIGHT / MAP_SIZE)) + 1f32,
                    (CELL_SIZE) - 2f32,
                    (SCREEN_HEIGHT / MAP_SIZE) - 2f32,
                    WHITE,
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
fn distance(aX: f32, aY: f32, bX: f32, bY: f32, angle: f32) -> f32 {
    return ((bX - aX) * (bX - aX) + (bY - aY) * (bY - aY)).sqrt() as f32;
}
fn draw_simple_background() {
    draw_rectangle(
        SCREEN_OFFSET,
        0f32,
        SCREEN_WIDTH,
        SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2f32,
        LIGHTGRAY,
    );
    draw_rectangle(
        SCREEN_OFFSET,
        SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2f32,
        SCREEN_WIDTH,
        SCREEN_HEIGHT,
        GRAY,
    );
}
struct Player {
    rect: Rect,
    deltaX: f32,
    deltaY: f32,
    angle: f32,
}
impl Player {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            rect: Rect::new(150f32, 150f32, 4f32, 4f32),
            angle: (PI / 2f32) + 1f32,
            deltaX: (PI / 2f32) + 1f32.cos() * 5f32,
            deltaY: (PI / 2f32) + 1f32.sin() * 5f32,
        }
    }

    pub fn drawRay(&mut self, RenderType: bool) {
        let mut rayAngle: f32 = self.angle - DEGREE * 30f32;
        if rayAngle < 0f32 {
            rayAngle += 2f32 * PI;
        }
        if rayAngle > 2f32 * PI {
            rayAngle -= 2f32 * PI
        }

        let mut rayX: f32 = self.rect.x;
        let mut rayY: f32 = self.rect.y;

        let mut finalDistance: f32 = 100000f32;

        let mut Yoffset: f32 = 0f32;
        let mut Xoffset: f32 = 0f32;
        let mut mapX: f32 = 0f32;
        let mut mapY: f32 = 0f32;

        for n in 1..(FIELD_OF_VIEW * RAYS_PER_DEGREE) as usize {
            let mut wallColor: [f32; 4] = [1f32, 0f32, 0f32, 1f32];

            let mut horizontalDistance: f32 = 100000f32;
            let mut horizontalX: f32 = self.rect.x;
            let mut horizontalY: f32 = self.rect.y;

            let arcTan: f32 = -1f32 / rayAngle.tan();
            let mut maxChecks: f32 = 0f32;
            if rayAngle > PI {
                rayY = self.rect.y.floor() - (self.rect.y % CELL_SIZE);
                rayX = ((self.rect.y - rayY) * arcTan + self.rect.x);
                Yoffset = -CELL_SIZE;
                Xoffset = -Yoffset * arcTan;
            } else if rayAngle < PI {
                rayY = self.rect.y - (self.rect.y % CELL_SIZE) + CELL_SIZE;
                rayX = (self.rect.y - rayY) * arcTan + self.rect.x;
                Yoffset = CELL_SIZE;
                Xoffset = -Yoffset * arcTan;
            } else {
                rayX = self.rect.x;
                rayY = self.rect.y;
                maxChecks = MAP_SIZE;
            }
            while maxChecks < MAP_SIZE {
                mapX = rayX / CELL_SIZE;
                mapY = rayY / CELL_SIZE;
                if mapX > MAP_SIZE - 1f32 {
                    mapX = MAP_SIZE - 1f32
                }
                if mapX < 0f32 {
                    mapX = 0f32;
                }
                if mapY > MAP_SIZE - 1f32 {
                    mapY = MAP_SIZE - 1f32
                }
                if mapY < 0f32 {
                    mapY = 0f32;
                }
                if level[mapY as usize][mapX as usize] > 0f32 {
                    maxChecks = MAP_SIZE;
                    horizontalX = rayX;
                    horizontalY = rayY;
                    horizontalDistance =
                        distance(self.rect.x, self.rect.y, horizontalX, horizontalY, rayAngle);
                } else {
                    rayX += Xoffset;
                    rayY += Yoffset;
                    maxChecks += 1f32;
                }
            }

            let mut verticalDistance: f32 = 100000f32;
            let mut verticalX: f32 = self.rect.x;
            let mut verticalY: f32 = self.rect.y;

            let negativeTan: f32 = -1f32 * rayAngle.tan();
            maxChecks = 0f32;
            if (rayAngle > (PI / 2f32)) && (rayAngle < (3f32 * PI) / 2f32) {
                rayX = self.rect.x.floor() - (self.rect.x % CELL_SIZE);
                rayY = ((self.rect.x - rayX) * negativeTan + self.rect.y);
                Xoffset = -CELL_SIZE;
                Yoffset = -Xoffset * negativeTan;
            } else if (rayAngle < (PI / 2f32)) || (rayAngle > (3f32 * PI) / 2f32) {
                rayX = self.rect.x - (self.rect.x % CELL_SIZE) + CELL_SIZE;
                rayY = (self.rect.x - rayX) * negativeTan + self.rect.y;
                Xoffset = CELL_SIZE;
                Yoffset = -Xoffset * negativeTan;
            } else {
                rayX = self.rect.x;
                rayY = self.rect.y;
                maxChecks = MAP_SIZE;
            }
            while maxChecks < MAP_SIZE {
                mapX = rayX / CELL_SIZE;
                mapY = rayY / CELL_SIZE;
                if mapY > MAP_SIZE - 1f32 {
                    mapY = MAP_SIZE - 1f32;
                }
                if mapY < 0f32 {
                    mapY = 0f32;
                }
                if mapX > MAP_SIZE - 1f32 {
                    mapX = MAP_SIZE - 1f32;
                }
                if mapX < 0f32 {
                    mapX = 0f32;
                }
                if level[mapY as usize][mapX as usize] > 0f32 {
                    maxChecks = CELL_SIZE;
                    verticalX = rayX;
                    verticalY = rayY;
                    verticalDistance =
                        distance(self.rect.x, self.rect.y, verticalX, verticalY, rayAngle);
                } else {
                    rayX += Xoffset;
                    rayY += Yoffset;
                    maxChecks += 1f32;
                }
            }
            if verticalDistance <= horizontalDistance {
                rayX = verticalX;
                rayY = verticalY;
                finalDistance = verticalDistance;
                wallColor = [0.8f32, 0f32, 0f32, 1f32]; // different wall shading
            } else {
                rayX = horizontalX;
                rayY = horizontalY;
                finalDistance = horizontalDistance;
            }

            let mut correctionAngle: f32 = self.angle - rayAngle;
            if correctionAngle < 0f32 {
                correctionAngle += 2f32 * PI;
            }
            if correctionAngle > 2f32 * PI {
                correctionAngle -= 2f32 * PI;
            }
            finalDistance = finalDistance * correctionAngle.cos();

            for x in 0..2 {
                // distance shading
                wallColor[x] = wallColor[x] - (finalDistance / 500f32);
            }
            let lineHeight: f32 = (MAP_SIZE * SCREEN_HEIGHT) / finalDistance;

            if RenderType {
                draw_line(
                    self.rect.x + 2f32,
                    self.rect.y + 2f32,
                    rayX,
                    rayY,
                    3f32,
                    Color::new(wallColor[0], wallColor[1], wallColor[2], wallColor[3]),
                );
            } else {
                draw_line(
                    SCREEN_OFFSET
                        + (SCREEN_WIDTH / (FIELD_OF_VIEW * RAYS_PER_DEGREE)) * (n as f32 - 1f32)
                        + (SCREEN_OFFSET / (FIELD_OF_VIEW * RAYS_PER_DEGREE) / 2f32),
                    (SCREEN_HEIGHT - lineHeight) / 2f32,
                    SCREEN_OFFSET
                        + ((SCREEN_WIDTH) / (FIELD_OF_VIEW * RAYS_PER_DEGREE)) * (n as f32 - 1f32)
                        + ((SCREEN_OFFSET) / (FIELD_OF_VIEW * RAYS_PER_DEGREE) / 2f32),
                    ((SCREEN_HEIGHT - lineHeight) / 2f32) + lineHeight,
                    SCREEN_WIDTH / (FIELD_OF_VIEW * RAYS_PER_DEGREE) / 1f32,
                    Color::new(wallColor[0], wallColor[1], wallColor[2], wallColor[3]),
                );
            }

            rayAngle += DEGREE / 2f32;
            if rayAngle < 0f32 {
                rayAngle += 2f32 * PI;
            }
            if rayAngle > 2f32 * PI {
                rayAngle -= 2f32 * PI
            }
        }
    }
    pub fn update(&mut self, dt: f32) {
        if is_key_down(KeyCode::Left) {
            self.angle -= PLAYER_SPEED;
            if self.angle < 0f32 {
                self.angle += 2f32 * PI;
            }
            self.deltaX = self.angle.cos() * 5f32 * PLAYER_ROTATE_SPEED;
            self.deltaY = self.angle.sin() * 5f32 * PLAYER_ROTATE_SPEED;
        }
        if is_key_down(KeyCode::Right) {
            self.angle += PLAYER_SPEED;
            if self.angle > 2f32 * PI {
                self.angle -= 2f32 * PI;
            }
            self.deltaX = self.angle.cos() * 5f32 * PLAYER_ROTATE_SPEED;
            self.deltaY = self.angle.sin() * 5f32 * PLAYER_ROTATE_SPEED;
        }
        if is_key_down(KeyCode::W) {
            self.rect.x += self.deltaX;
            self.rect.y += self.deltaY;
        }
        if is_key_down(KeyCode::S) {
            self.rect.x -= self.deltaX;
            self.rect.y -= self.deltaY;
        }
    }
    pub fn draw(&self) {
        draw_rectangle(self.rect.x, self.rect.y, self.rect.w, self.rect.h, BLUE);
        draw_line(
            self.rect.x + 2.0,
            self.rect.y + 2.0,
            self.rect.x + self.deltaX * 5f32,
            self.rect.y + self.deltaY * 5f32,
            2f32,
            BLUE,
        );
    }
}

#[macroquad::main("Raycaster")]
async fn main() {
    request_new_screen_size(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    let mut player = Player::new();

    loop {
        clear_background(BLACK);

        player.update(get_frame_time());

        draw_simple_background();
        player.drawRay(false);
        if is_key_down(KeyCode::Tab) {
            clear_background(BLACK);
            draw_level();
            player.draw();
            player.drawRay(true);
        }

        next_frame().await
    }
}
```

Where I think the problem is exactly:

```
if rayAngle > PI {
    rayY = self.rect.y.floor() - (self.rect.y % CELL_SIZE);
    rayX = ((self.rect.y - rayY) * arcTan + self.rect.x);
    Yoffset = -CELL_SIZE;
    Xoffset = -Yoffset * arcTan;
} else if rayAngle < PI {
    rayY = self.rect.y - (self.rect.y % CELL_SIZE) + CELL_SIZE;
    rayX = (self.rect.y - rayY) * arcTan + self.rect.x;
    Yoffset = CELL_SIZE;
    Xoffset = -Yoffset * arcTan;
} else {
    rayX = self.rect.x;
    rayY = self.rect.y;
    maxChecks = MAP_SIZE;
}
while maxChecks < MAP_SIZE {
    mapX = rayX / CELL_SIZE;
    mapY = rayY / CELL_SIZE;
    if mapX > MAP_SIZE - 1f32 {
        mapX = MAP_SIZE - 1f32
    }
    if mapX < 0f32 {
        mapX = 0f32;
    }
    if mapY > MAP_SIZE - 1f32 {
        mapY = MAP_SIZE - 1f32
    }
    if mapY < 0f32 {
        mapY = 0f32;
    }
    if level[mapY as usize][mapX as usize] > 0f32 {
        maxChecks = MAP_SIZE;
        horizontalX = rayX;
        horizontalY = rayY;
        horizontalDistance =
            distance(self.rect.x, self.rect.y, horizontalX, horizontalY, rayAngle);
    } else {
        rayX += Xoffset;
        rayY += Yoffset;
        maxChecks += 1f32;
    }
}
```

[image: An image of what the bug looks like while rendering.]

The program throws out 2 rays per call, one for vertical walls and one for horizontal. the problem happens with both, vertical overlapping horizontal when it shouldn't and vice versa.

The distance between the player and the wall is calculated with an i32 then converted into a usize, aka float to int. I think this is where the error is, but I have made no progress in fixing it.
any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: *"The distance between the player and the wall is calculated with an i32"*- I guess you mean `f32`?

Comment: *"The code, in full"* - I highly doubt that, this code has tons of undefined constants. Please provide an actual [MRE].

Comment: Voting to close, as a problem this complex can't be fixed without being able to reproduce it, and >20hours later so far the question was not [edit]ed to provide a [MRE]. Although I'm kinda sad about it, this sounded like a fun problem.